# Javascript confirmation and navigate

Tags: javascript, if-statement, window.location

I have the following snippets, which are self explanatory:

HTML:

```
<input
    class="button"
    style="height:30px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: auto; vertical-align: middle;"
    onclick="disp_confirm();"
    tabindex="3"
    type="submit"
    value="Delete">
```

JavaScript:

```
function disp_confirm() {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?')) {
        window.location.href = 'https://sub.domain.com/details.php?action=delete';
    }
}
```

For some reason, this will not navigate this page. All I want is it to basically reload the page and adding on an `action=delete`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nowhere in that code you posted is there an attempt to set the "disabled" property of anything.

Comment: @Pointy - I know.. different script. I don't think it has to do with this actually. I will remove from question

Comment: is iFrame in use ?.. Have u tried Chrome dev tool and see whats the issue .. mostly this seems cross-domain issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
window.location.search = 'action=delete';
```

Comment: Nope. Does it matter if it forces the user to resubmit the form?

Comment: What happens when you change the search property?

Comment: There must be some other error happening. Could you put an alert into the if block to be sure it's being executed?